# Trim Off Varying Last Special Characters in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

Below is a gsub approach for trimming off forward slashes from a data frame. Looking to find a more general solution for data.frame's with varying column counts.

```
helloToday <- data.frame(a = c("hello", "hello", "hello"), 
                 b = c("world","","world"),
                 c = c("","","today"))

helloToday
#      a     b     c
# 1 hello world      
# 2 hello            
# 3 hello world today  


# Returns the vector 
helloToday <- apply(helloToday, 1, function(x){ paste0("/", paste(x, collapse = "/")) })
# [1] "/hello/world/"      "/hello//"           "/hello/world/today"

# But I would like the trailing symbols to be trimmed off
# [1] "/hello/world"      "/hello"           "/hello/world/today"


gsub("\\/$", "", gsub("\\/$", "", helloToday))
# "/hello/world/"      "/hello//"           "/hello/world/today"

helloToday <- gsub("\\//$", "", helloToday)
helloToday <- gsub("\\/$", "", helloToday)
# "/hello/world/"      "/hello//"           "/hello/world/today"
```

Is there a solution which would allow varying column counts, where "/" or "//" or even "///////////"?

Comment: `+` is the regex symbol for "one or more", so `"\\/+$"` would match any number of `/` off the end of the string.

Comment: Actually, there is no point escaping `/`. Use `sub("/+$", "", helloToday)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is the regex modifier for "one or more", so `"/+$"` would match any number of `/` off the end of the string.

```
gsub("/+$", "", helloToday)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ann alternative approach to regexing after the fact is to build it differently to begin with:

```
apply(helloToday, 1, function(x) do.call(file.path, as.list(x[!x %in% ''])))


## [1] "hello/world"       "hello"             "hello/world/today"
```

If the leading slash is needed:

```
apply(helloToday, 1, function(x) do.call(file.path, as.list(c('', x[!x %in% '']))))
```